# any little windows tool which runs a background process, and terminates immediately?

Tags: php, windows

Background: I am calling a long-running executable (2 minutes) from PHP. PHPs `exec(longprocess)` function **waits for the process to terminate** before running the next (rendering the HTML, for example).

I want a program that terminates immediately but allows me to run a program in the background so that I can do a `exec(backgrounder longprocess)`, which leaves `longprocess` to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `start` command:

```
exec("start someprogram.exe");
```

Comment: Couldnt do even a `start sleep 5` in the background

Answer (score 0):

Try parallel processing: http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254